# Can you play online coop between the Master Chief Collection and the individual Halo games?

Tags: halo-4, halo-the-master-chief-collection

With the Master Chief Collection, are you able to play online coop with someone who has one of the actual halo games? For example, will I be able to play online coop on halo 4 with my friend while I'm on the Master Chief Collection but they're on the actual halo 4 disc?

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to play Halo MCC online with other people who are playing the individual games.

Confirmed by this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/halo/comments/7v19oa/my_son_wants_to_get_halo_mcc_but_can_he_only_play/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share).